# Best way to add an application straight onto an existing page in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm in the middle of learning Ruby on Rails, and I want to build a complete Blog website. I'm at the point where I have my basic static pages set up including the Home page. I know how to make the basic application for posting blog posts by itself, but I'm not sure how to add the feature to the body of my Home page. I'm assuming there is a straightforward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Without seeing your code, this is only general steps on how to go about the problem. Given that Rails follows MVC pattern I'm going to structure the solution in the same way.

1. Model: Sounds like you already have this working. Let's say you have a model for blog posts called `Post`
2. View: from your question, you want to add the form to create a blog post directly to the home page. So on the template for your home page, where you want to show the form, add `<%= render 'posts/form' %>`
3. Controller: you'll need to initialize an empty blog post to build the form that you just added to the page. In your page's controller action (e.g. `pages#home`) you'll need to `@post ||= Post.new` - the `||=` allows for the case where you've tried to fill out the form and submit but the model has validation errors.

If you have any specific problems following these steps, post another question or comment.

Comment: Thanks for helping me add clarity :) I have not yet added the Posting Model. Basically I only have the static pages at this point. Am I able to generate the model in the same application per usual and then link to it or will it mess up my controller? I guess my problem is that I don't know how to put the static pages app and a blogger app together without messing everything up. I only know how to do each on completely different applications.

Comment: OK you can definitely add blog posts to the existing application - you can have as many models, controllers etc as you like. If you run a generator e.g. `rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text` in the current application, it will generate a new model, controller, and directory of views that will not interfere with what's already there.

Comment: If you have further questions, it's best to ask specifics in a new SO question - as it is this one is verging on being too general

Comment: Thank you! That answered my question. I'll work on being more specific in the future!